# SQL - When creating a table, how can I make it so a column is required when another column meets a certain requirement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. So this is what I have right now:

```
CREATE TABLE Product 
(
    product_id          INT             NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    product_code        CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,   --For a book use  'BOOK'
    product_name        VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
    product_desc        VARCHAR(5000),
    book_author         INT,
    book_publisher      INT,
    product_price       SMALLMONEY      NOT NULL    CHECK (product_price >= 0),     
    FOREIGN KEY (book_author)       REFERENCES Author
);
```

So I would like to make it so that book_author and book_publisher cannot be null if product_code == 'BOOK'.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: If a CHECK comes after all the column definitions then it can mention any columns. And A IMPLIES B is (NOT A) OR B.

Comment: I am still learning, so please bare with me. Could this still be done under the same CREATE TABLE command, or would I have to do ALTER or something?

Comment: Yes, Find an SQL-Server reference. Eg googling 'sql-server create table [Microsoft Developer Network CREATE Statements (Transact-SQL) ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)

Comment: Side-note: always give your constraints (primary keys, indexes, foreign keys ...) a name. If you don't SQL Server will assign a random name to it. If you have multiple clients in the field, each constraint name will be different. This makes scripting a lot more cumbersome if your decide to change your constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
  product_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
  , product_code CHAR(4) NOT NULL
  , product_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
  , product_desc VARCHAR(5000)
  , book_author INT
  , book_publisher INT
  , product_price SMALLMONEY NOT NULL CHECK (product_price >= 0)
  , CONSTRAINT CHK_author CHECK (
    CASE 
      WHEN product_code = 'BOOK' AND (book_author IS NULL OR book_publisher IS NULL) THEN 0
      ELSE 1
    END = 1
    )
);
```

`CHK_author` constraint will check if your `product_code` is `BOOK`, and if it is, then it will check whether `book_author` OR `book_publisher` are `NULL` values. If one of them is - it will restrict statement.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dee58/3/0)

Comment: So for my knowledge, WHEN is like a if statement and it needs to be put after CASE, END is the end of the case, and then if the CASE returns 0 the command will not be executed and the if it returns a 1 it will?

Comment: @kingcobra1986 That's correct. If `CASE` statement returns 0 (`product_code = 'BOOK'` and either `book_author` or `book_publisher` IS `NULL`) and will try to compare it to 1. In this case it will fail and restrict update/insert. In other cases, it will return 1 and query will run fine.

Comment: One more question, should this be after the 'FOREIGN KEY (book_author) REFERENCES Products.Author,' call or before it?

Comment: @kingcobra1986 Make it last, yes. Although - I don't think that there's any difference.

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [product_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [product_code] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [product_name] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [product_desc] [varchar](5000) NULL,
    [book_author] [int] NULL,
    [book_publisher] [int] NULL,
    [product_price] [smallmoney] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [product_id] ASC )
)
Go

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Product]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Product] CHECK  (  
    (
        ( [product_code] <> 'BOOK' )
        OR
        (
            ( [book_author] IS NOT NULL ) 
            AND ( [book_publisher] IS NOT NULL )          
        ) 
    )    
    AND         
    ( [product_price] >= 0 )
)
Go

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Product] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_Product]
Go
```

One constraint pair row.